# Why are the Majus mentioned in 22:17 but not in 6:23 of the Holy Quran?

Tags: quran

2:62 :
Indeed, those who believed and those who were Jews or Christians or Sabeans [before Prophet Muhammad] – those [among them] who believed in Allah and the Last Day and did righteousness – will have their reward with their Lord, and no fear will there be concerning them, nor will they grieve.

22:17 :

Indeed, those who have believed and those who were Jews and the Sabeans and the Christians and the Magians and those who associated with Allah - Allah will judge between them on the Day of Resurrection. Indeed Allah is, over all things, Witness.

Answer (score 2):

The two verses are for different purposes. You can also see that the second verse mentions "those who associated with Allah" i.e. the idolaters and the first verse does not.

The first verse is about those who used to follow true prophets in the past. Allah says about them that those of them who believed before Muhammad (SAW) will enter Jannah.

The second verse is simply Allah saying He will judge between all these religions, and He does not mention any of them as being granted Jannah. So, religions that were false from the beginning like the Majus and idolaters are also mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.